# isainfo "-k" vs "-n" option

Tags: solaris, 32-vs-64-bit

I am wondering about the difference between the two commands

```
isainfo -k
isainfo -n
```

on Solaris. I understand that the first is used to check if the kernel is running in 32-bit or 64-bit mode, and the man page says about the second

```
     -n    Prints the name of the native instruction set used  by
           portable applications supported by the current version
           of the operating system.
```

On a test machine running Solaris in 64-bit mode the output of both commands is "amd64".
So my questions are:

- Can the output of the two commands be different?
- If I have an installation script that wants to check the prerequisites before extracting and starting 64-bit software, which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By different you mean 32 vs 64?  No.

Sparc box output:

```
jmcnama@SNEDAP03 ~> isainfo -k  -v
64-bit sparcv9 kernel modules
jmcnama@SNEDAP03 ~> isainfo -n  -v
64-bit sparcv9 applications
        ima fmaf vis2 vis popc
```

Add the -v option to check for the 64bit kernel.  If the system has a 64 bit kernel it supports 64 bit executable images.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still wonder why there are two different options, if `isainfo -k` and `isainfo -n` will both report "sparc" or "sparcv9" (resp. "i386" or "amd64" on a Intel box). In other words, what is the difference between *"the kernel is running in 64-bit mode"* and *"64-bit applications are supported"*. - If you have any information that could reduce my confusion I would be grateful.